# ArgumentException was unhandled by user code (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, web-services, entity-framework

I'm developing an MVC application using Visual Studio 2010.

I created 3 projects : 1- dll library, 2- WebService, 3- WPF Application

Inside the dll, I have an Entity Framework 4 wich will be used by the webservice to get data and sent them to the WPF app.

My problem is that : I get the "ArgumentException was unhandled by user code" error when I try to call a function that instantiate an Entity Data Model from the WebService.

I created a console project (for test purpose) in the same solution and added a reference to the dll library and copied the App.Config to that project and got it works. But when i do the same thing with the Webservice I get always the same error.

Help please

Comment: You specify an general error message, which is not informative. Can you tell us the error message text that follows after the Argument Exception text? Perhaps simply renaming the App.config to Web.config will solve the problem.

Comment: This is the error that I get : http://i.imgur.com/EZjHZ.png

Comment: Look inside the exception (vide detail) and check the source file name and line number, it should show you where the exception was thrown. One of the arguments of some of the underlying code is wrong. And add that link to the question, not only as a comment!

Comment: It's pointing me to this : using (var context = new EntityDataModelContainer()) {...} in the dll library project. What I can't understand is : I did the same thing with a console app and it worked, why it's not working in the WebService ?

Comment: you need to provide more info, for instance the code, parameters values at the time of that failing code etc... We cannot really guess what is happening there

Comment: @zmilojko It was not a problem in the code, but just the way I had to do it with teh WebService ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, found it.

The WebService reads the `Web.config` file, so it's useless to copy the `App.config` to this kind of projects like (ASP.NET websites or WebServices) it will work just for the desktop applications (Console, WinForms, WPF, ...).

**Solution :**

Copy the content of the App.config from the .dll and paste it in the Web.config file, like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EntityDataModelContainer" ... />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```